# Android studio errors in where clause

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i need to search for a particular word from my words table and display the meaning in a text view .... please help me out

my database helper class is :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by priya on 4/2/2015.
 */
public class wordshelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int version = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE = "phords.db";
    private static final String TABLE= "words";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREAT = "create table words(id integer not null , " +
            "word text primary key not null , description text not null);";

    public wordshelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREAT);
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void insertContract(Contract c) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from words";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID , count);
        values.put(COLUMN_WORD, c.getWord());
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, c.getDescription());
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public Cursor getMeaning(String search_word,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String[] projections = {COLUMN_WORD,COLUMN_DESCRIPTION};
        String selection = COLUMN_WORD + "LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {search_word};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE,projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

my dictionary java class is :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Me on 27-Aug-15.
 */
public class Dictionary extends Activity {
    EditText searches;
    TextView words,descriptions;
    private EditText resultText;
    SQLiteDatabase sql;
    wordshelper wordhelp = new wordshelper(this);
    String search_word;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dictionary);
        searches = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
        words = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvword);
        descriptions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdescription);
        resultText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
    }
    public void onSearch(View v)
    {
        search_word = searches.getText().toString();
        wordhelp = new wordshelper(getApplicationContext());
        sql = wordhelp.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = wordhelp.getMeaning(search_word,sql);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String WORD = getString(0);
            String DESCRIPTION = getString(1);
            words.setText(WORD);
            descriptions.setText(DESCRIPTION);
        }
    }
 public void onSpeech(View v)
 {
     if (v.getId()==R.id.imageButton)
     {
         EditText result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
         promptSpeechInput();
     }
 }
    public void promptSpeechInput(){
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "say something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Dictionary.this,"sorry! your device doesn't support speech",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_code,int result_code,Intent i )
    {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code) {
            case 100:
                if (result_code == RESULT_OK && i !=null)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    resultText.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

my dictionary xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:background="@drawable/marshmellows">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Word/phrase"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Meaning"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok"
        android:id="@+id/Bok"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etsearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onSearch"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/r"
        android:onClick="onSpeech"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bsearch" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView10"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my contract class is :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

/**
 * Created by Me on 13-Sep-15.
 */
public class Contract {
    String word,description;
    public void setWord(String word) {this.word=word;}
    public String getWord() {return this.word;}
    public void setDescription(String description){this.description=description;}
    public String getDescription(){return this.description;}
}
```

someone please help me out .... waiting for ur reply

my logcat says :

```
09-19 07:25:52.471  25612-25612/com.example.pro.phord E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pro.phord, PID: 25612
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:360)
            at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:376)
            at com.example.pro.phord.Dictionary.onSearch(Dictionary.java:47)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe the exact nature of your problem, i.e. what error are you getting or what exactly does not work as expected. Just posting the code asking the community to debug it should be avoided, but asking for help on a specific error/problem is much more likely to produce an answer you are looking for.

Comment: @plamut .... i got the answer ... thank u

Comment: I'm glad the community was able to help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's your problem:

```
String selection = COLUMN_WORD + "LIKE ?"
```

It needs a space:

```
String selection = COLUMN_WORD + " LIKE ?"
```

As mentioned by:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT word, description FROM words WHERE wordLIKE ?
```

Comment: i tried entering the clause the way you told me to but it still says UNFORTUNATELY STOPPED when i press the search button :( :( ... i dont know whats wrong ... Is everything else correct ?

Comment: i tried it but i got another error .....  please look into it and let me know @kenvan

Comment: You should have a new callstack with an exception in your logcat. That should say what's wrong and on what line of code it failed.

Answer (score 0):

it kept going into the res file because i didnt mention the cursor in the if statement ... i just changed the if condition in the dictionary class as

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String WORD = cursor.getString(0);
            String DESCRIPTION = cursor.getString(1);
//remaining code 
}
```